# Access is denied with os.rmdir

Tags: python, minecraft

I know this has probably been asked a million times, but I can't seem to solve my issue.
My friends don't know how to install Minecraft mods properly, so I'm trying to make a python script to automatically send the files to the right directories. They don't know how to clear their mods, config, and flan directory. So I tried using

```
os.rmdir('C:\\Users\\Nuriel\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods')
```

to clear the mod folder and delete it as well so I could move the mods folder from the modpack to .minecraft. Problem is, instead of removing the mods directory, I'm hit with an error that says

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Nuriel\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods'
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this? Could I be able to run it as an administrator and run it from there?
tried solutions:

```
os.rmdir()
os.remove()
send2trash.send2trash()
```

Comment: @shriakhilc The comment you sent doesn't quite make sense with an Access Denied error.

Comment: Is the directory empty? `rmdir` needs the target directory to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```py
import os
os.system('del "C:\\Users\\Nuriel\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods\\*"')
os.system('rmdir "C:\\Users\\Nuriel\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods"')
```

Also, please make sure that if you are sending the file, your username should not be 'Nuriel'. I recommend asking the username of the user currently running.

```py
import os
username = input("Your username: ")
os.system('del "C:\\Users\\Nuriel\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods\\*"')
os.system('rmdir "C:\\Users\\Nuriel\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\mods"')
```

If this does not work, try running the command prompt as administrator, then running it using the command line.

Comment: have you try to open your cmd as administrator and run your script?

Comment: I have tried running it as an administrator, I also did the method above, but the del command didn't seem to delete anything as the directory was still there

Comment: @Nuriel Does my updated script work now?

Answer (score 0):

did you run your ide or pad or whatever you running your script from as admin?

Comment: Yes, I did, it hasn't made any difference.